# Upgrading NFS/NIS Shared `/home` Setup

Tags: security, nis, nfs, home-directory

I am currently managing a network of workstations running different flavours of Ubuntu. The server (also Ubuntu) runs a `NIS` server and exports a shared `/home` directory over `NFS` (in v3 compatibility mode). Workstations are configured to mount `server:/home` to `/home` using static `fstab` entries. Users can log-in from any workstation to their account while their `/home/xxx` directory is always accessible (Quite old-school).

The problem (one out of many of course) with the current setup is, users can see the whole `/home`. If users are not careful with file permissions in their home directories, their data can be accessed by other users.

I need advice on how to improve/upgrade the system, preferably with minimal change to the current setup.

Comment: This is how linux was designed and would be the case regardless of nis/nfs involvement.  If it is a problem mount, /home/userdir to /home/userdir on the machines. If you want roaming profiles switch to a windows environment (It is something Microsoft actually did VERY well). Else look for roaming profile solutions online?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately migrating to Windows is not feasible. I will look into roaming profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution i use at work working well and no security problem so far: autofs
You can find a lot of information about 'autofs' on the Net easily.

Make sure each user folder are 'chmod 700' and owned by them.

:-)

Here is a quick sample of the config i use:

**Start NFS home directory automount:**
Now, on the NIS client, set up automount to handle /home. In /etc/auto.master:
    `/home /etc/auto.home`

And create /etc/auto.home with these contents:
    `* rw,sync hostname.of.nfs.server:/home/&`

Then restart autofs, and make sure it starts at boot:

> service autofs restart
>       chkconfig autofs on
>       service nfs start
>       service ypbind start  (nis)
>       chkconfig nfs on; chkconfig ypbind on;

Configuration of NIS is another subject.

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you.(Unfortunately currently I do not have minimum rep to up-vote the answer!)

Comment: the /home folder must be empty on the client that use autofs for this config to work.